# buscador con FULLTEXT no muestra alias

Tags: php, mysql

veréis estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en PHP. He leído por foros que el buscador se hace mas optimo con FULLTEXT que con LIKE. El caso es que he hecho un mix de ambos en el siguientes script:

```
<h3>Buscar</h3>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id">

     <input type="search" name="busqueda"><input type="submit" value="Buscar">

</form>
<?php

   $busqueda = (isset($_POST['busqueda']))?$_POST['busqueda']:"";

if($busqueda<>''){

$trozos = explode("",$busqueda);
$numero = count($trozos);

  if($numero==1){

     $SQL = "SELECT nombre_beca, cuantia, año FROM tabla WHERE nombre_beca LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR año=$busqueda LIMIT 50";
     $resultSQL =  mysqli_query ($GLOBALS['conn'], $SQL);
     while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQL)){

        echo "

          <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre de Beca</th>
            <th>Cuantía</th>
            <th>Año</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_beca']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['cuantia']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['año']."</td>
          </tr>

          </table>

           ";

       }

     }else if($numero>1) {

       $SQL = "SELECT MATCH (nombre_beca) AGAINST ('busqueda') AS nombre_beca, cuantia, año FROM tabla MATCH (nombre_beca) AGAINST ('$busqueda') OR año=$busqueda ORDER BY nombre_beca DESC LIMIT 50";

       $resultSQL =  mysqli_query ($GLOBALS['conn'], $SQL);
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQL)){

        echo "

          <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre de Beca</th>
            <th>Cuantía</th>
            <th>Año</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_beca']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['cuantia']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['año']."</td>
          </tr>

          </table>

           ";

       }else{


          echo "No has introducido nada</br>";


     }

     ?>
```

Básicamente el primer If comprueba si solo se introduce una palabra y el segundo If si hay mas de una. El primer if lo hace sin problemas, pero el segundo me dice PHP que la consulta esta mal. Luego lo compruebo en PHPMyAdmin y sale en los dos valores que se muestran esto: 0.062016263604164124 y 0

La estructura de mi tabla mysql es asi:

```
CREATE TABLE `becas` (

`id_beca` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre_beca` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
`cuantia` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`año` year(4) NOT NULL,
`codigo_persona_beca` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_beca`),
KEY `fk_personal_beca`(`codigo_persona_beca`),
FULLTEXT KEY `nombre_beca` (`nombre_beca`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_personal_beca` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_persona_beca`) REFERENCES `datos_personales` (`id_personal`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Sale un numero muy raro y luego el segundo resultado sale 0. Tendria que salir el nombre de la beca y no un numero por eso puse el ALIAS.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la estructura de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Vale ya esta solucionada la pregunta. Lo que pasaba es que llamaba a la relevancia de la funcion MATCH(). Entonces me sacaba dos valores y el valor con decimales era la medida con mas coincidencia en la busqueda, el valor 0 es un registro que sacaba pero que no coincidia en ninguna palabra de la busqueda.

Simplemente lo he quitado del Select pero manteniendo la funcion en la condición.

```
$SQL = "SELECT nombre_beca, cuantia, año FROM tabla WHERE MATCH (nombre_beca) AGAINST ('$busqueda') OR año=$busqueda ORDER BY nombre_beca DESC LIMIT 50";
```

He encontrado la información [aquí](https://programacion.net/articulo/busquedas_de_texto_completo_225)